# ¿Por qué aparece número inválido cuando el tipo de dato si es el que corresponde?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy haciendo un script actualmente en el cual debo ingresar parametricamente NUMRUT_EMP y DCTO_EMP, pero al momento de ingresar el RUT me aparece que el número es inválido y desconozco el motivo debido a que es el tipo de dato que corresponde (lo traigo desde la tabla) y sólo ingreso 8 números (11846972). Ayuda, a continuación del código mostraré el error.

````
DECLARE
    V_NOMBRE_EMP EMPLEADO.NOMBRE_EMP%TYPE;
    V_APPATERNO_EMP EMPLEADO.APPATERNO_EMP%TYPE;
    V_APMATERNO_EMP EMPLEADO.APMATERNO_EMP%TYPE;
    V_NUMRUT_EMP EMPLEADO.NUMRUT_EMP%TYPE := &B_NUMRUT_EMP;
    V_DVRUT_EMP EMPLEADO.DVRUT_EMP%TYPE;
    V_SUELDO_EMP EMPLEADO.SUELDO_EMP%TYPE;
    V_DCTO_EMP NUMBER(2) := &B_DCTO_EMP;
    V_BONIFICACION V_SUELDO_EMP%TYPE;
    V_ID_CATEGORIA_EMP EMPLEADO.ID_CATEGORIA_EMP%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        E.NOMBRE_EMP,
        E.APPATERNO_EMP,
        E.APMATERNO_EMP,
        E.DVRUT_EMP,
        E.SUELDO_EMP,
        E.ID_CATEGORIA_EMP
        INTO
            V_NOMBRE_EMP,
            V_APPATERNO_EMP,
            V_APMATERNO_EMP,
            V_DVRUT_EMP,
            V_SUELDO_EMP,
            V_ID_CATEGORIA_EMP
    FROM
        EMPLEADO E INNER JOIN CATEGORIA_EMPLEADO CE
        ON (E.ID_CATEGORIA_EMP = CE.ID_CATEGORIA_EMP)
    WHERE
        E.NUMRUT_EMP = V_NUMRUT_EMP AND
        E.SUELDO_EMP BETWEEN 0 AND 5000000 AND
        CE.ID_CATEGORIA_EMP <> 'Ejecutivo de Arriendo';
        
    V_BONIFICACION := V_SUELDO_EMP * (V_DCTO_EMP/100);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATOS CALCULO BONIFICACION EXTRA DEL ' || V_DCTO_EMP || '% DEL SUELDO');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nombre Empleado : ' || V_NOMBRE_EMP || ' ' || V_APPATERNO_EMP || ' ' || V_APMATERNO_EMP);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RUN : ' || V_NUMRUT_EMP || '-' || V_DVRUT_EMP);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sueldo : ' || V_SUELDO_EMP);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bonificación extra : ' || V_BONIFICACION);
END;

Informe de error -
ORA-01722: número no válido
ORA-06512: en línea 12
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Trata de verificar la estructura de la tabla, y ver a qué tipo de dato corresponde, revisa muy bien a que función o procedimiento lo estás mandando y los tipos de datos que reciben.
El **ORA-01722** es el típico error que sale cuando tratas de manipular un dato numérico con uno que no lo es (como varchar) y al ejecutar tu script no hace match y saca el error.

Comment: Buenas Jose, pero ese es el problema, yo ya verifiqué el tipo de dato, e incluso antes este script funcionaba, no moví nada literalmente, y ahora no me funciona. Incluso volví a una versión de una hora específica para ver si toqué algo pero nada. No sé qué más hacer debido a que el tipo de dato de numrut_emp en la tabla es number de 8 y eso es justamente lo que estoy ingresando.